# Error when trying to call Adapter.notifyDataSetChanged in UltimateRecyclerView

Tags: android, list, android-recyclerview, adapter

I am using the UltimateRecyclerView (extends the RecycerView with a lot of great features)

But I am getting an Error...

Why am I getting :

```
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: ViewStub must have a valid layoutResource
                      at android.view.ViewStub.inflate(ViewStub.java:284)
                      at android.view.ViewStub.setVisibility(ViewStub.java:235)
                      at com.marshalchen.ultimaterecyclerview.UltimateRecyclerView.updateHelperDisplays(UltimateRecyclerView.java:862)
```

....

when trying to run this code:

```
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.View;

import com.marshalchen.ultimaterecyclerview.UltimateRecyclerView;
import com.yqritc.recyclerviewflexibledivider.HorizontalDividerItemDecoration;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    UltimateRecyclerView dhikrListe;
    MyAdapter myAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        dhikrListe = (UltimateRecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.ultimate_recyclerView);

        dhikrListe.setHasFixedSize(true);
        dhikrListe.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this)); //Hier könnten wir auch verschiedene Layouts festlegen. Bei der ListView, die vorher hatten, ist das Linearlayout fest eingestellt.

        dhikrListe.addItemDecoration(
                new HorizontalDividerItemDecoration.Builder(this)
                        .color(Color.GRAY)
                        .build()); // Der Divider trennt die Zeilen mit einem Strich

        myAdapter = new MyAdapter(this);

        dhikrListe.setAdapter(myAdapter); //Adapter wird gesetzt
    }

    public void add(View view){
        MyAdapter.dhikrListe.add(new Dhikr("Al-Hamdu lillah"));
        myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

}
```

?

Thanks a lot!

**EDIT**

Just Add an empty Layout_Ressource_file with name: empty_view.

Than it should work!

Thanks to answer below.

Comment: see this you will get the idea https://github.com/cymcsg/UltimateRecyclerView/issues/346

Answer (score 0):

Hello Not use new Instace of adapter used old instace

```
public void add(View view){
    myAdapter.dhikrListe.add(new Dhikr("Al-Hamdu lillah"));
    myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```